# Why Integer.valueOf cannot parse the hex string back to integer

Tags: java, hex

Why did the following code not work

```
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(Integer.toOctalString(-1), 8));
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString(-1), 2));
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(Integer.toHexString(-1), 16));
```

Comment: @CodeScale Incorrect. You can use `Integer.parseUnsignedInt()`

Answer (score 0):

If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Integer.toOctalString(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toOctalString-int-), you will find:

> Returns a string representation of the integer argument as an **unsigned** integer in base 8.
>
> [...]
>
> The value of the argument can be recovered from the returned string `s` by calling [`Integer.parseUnsignedInt(s, 8)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-int-).

Javadoc of [`Integer.toBinaryString(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-) and [`Integer.toHexString(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-) says exactly the same thing, except the base is of course different (`2` and `16`, respectively).

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(Integer.toOctalString(-1), 8));
System.out.println(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(Integer.toBinaryString(-1), 2));
System.out.println(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(Integer.toHexString(-1), 16));
```

*Output*

```
-1
-1
-1
```